# OpenLayers 3 right click event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to listen to right mouse click , i tried `"rightclick"` as in documentation says , but it doesn't work.

Can any one say why it doesn't work ???

```
map.on('rightclick', function (evt) {
            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
                if (typeof (feature.getId()) != "undefined") {
                    return feature;
                }
            });

            if (feature) {
                var registeredObjectId = -1;

                if (typeof MapObjects !== "undefined") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < MapObjects.ObjectResult.length; i++) {
                        if (feature.p.name === MapObjects.ObjectResult[i].Id) {
                            registeredObjectId = i;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
                var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

                if (registeredObjectId === -1) {
                    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                    $(element).popover({
                        'placement': 'top',
                        'html': true,
                        'content': "<a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='DeleteCoordinate(\"" + feature.getId() + "\")'>Delete</a>"
                    });
                    $(element).popover('show');
                    $(element2).popover('destroy');
                }
                else {
                    popup2.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                    console.log(MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Name);
                    console.log(MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Value);
                    $(element2).popover({
                        'placement': 'top',
                        'html': true,
                        'content': "<label>" + MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Name + "</label></br><label>" + MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Value + "</label></br><a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='DeleteCoordinate(\"" + feature.getId() + "\")'>Delete</a>"
                    });
                    $(element2).popover('show');
                    $(element).popover('destroy');
                }

            } else {
                $(element).popover('destroy');
                $(element2).popover('destroy');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32111223/4640499

Answer (score 1):

Try out this tutorial, someone got stuck with a similar problem and wrote some code to get around it  http://spatialnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/capturing-right-click-events-in.html